# How to force overwrite non-empty directories using `mv`

Tags: files, rsync, rename

I am wanting to move (not just copy) a group of files/directories to a different directory some of which have name clashes with files/directories in the target directory. My main objective is to move the files, so I can tolerate the non-empty directory being overwritten.

I am currently using `mv ... destination` however, occasionally I get

> mv: cannot move `target' to  /destination/target': Directory not empty

I tried `mv -f ... destination` with no success and since I want the files to be gone from their original location, `rsync` doesn't seem to be appropriate.

As a bonus, is there a good solution for preserving the files intended to be overwritten somehow maybe by renaming?

Comment: And what error do you get when you try your mv command?

Comment: You explicitly say that `rsync` is not what you want; why did you tag this with `rsync`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti I said it doesn't seem appropriate, but I am willing to be shown otherwise.

Comment: @suspectus Updated question.

Comment: if you use use `mv --backup=numbered` or one of the other options for the `--backup` switch, then `mv` will complete the merge and preserve the files intended to be overwritten

Comment: @bdowning this solves all my problems if you want to post it as the answer!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you use `mv --backup=numbered`
  (or one of the other options for the `--backup` switch),
then `mv` will complete the merge and preserve the files intended to be overwritten.

Comment: dumb answer - this will pollute your drive with `.~1~` folders

Comment: Worked for me: `mv --backup=t <source> <destination>`. Thanks!

Comment: Oh god, why did i listen to this advice, now i've got numbered directories everywhere. God damnit. I used the backup=t option. DO NOT USE THIS, THIS IS NOT THE ANSWER.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
SRC=/path/to/source
DST=/path/to/destination

for item in $SRC/*; do
    if [[ -f "$DST/$(basename "$item")" ]]; then
        newitem=$(basename $item)_old
        while [[ -f "$DST/$newitem" ]]; do
            newitem=${newitem}_old
        done
        mv "$DST/$(basename $item)" "$DST/$newitem"
    fi
    mv "$item" "$DST/$(basename $item)"
done
```

Comment: Instead of this script, one could directly run the `cp` followed by the `mv` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mc` (Midnight Commander) inside the screen and the folders with with `Ins` and `F6`