# Merely moving a directory inside another using mv

Tags: mv

I just came across this weirdness: I want to do the equivalent of dragging a directory inside another (moving it). Trival day-to-day task for a GUI.

here is my tree:

```
.
├── assemble.py
├── Basic Information Retrieval.ipynb
├── Basic Information Retrieval.tex
├── Book
│   ├── book.aux
│   ├── book.log
│   ├── Book_master.tex
│   ├── book.out
│   ├── book.pdf
│   ├── book.tex
│   ├── book.toc
│   ├── build.sh
│   ├── chapter_0.tex
│   ├── chapter_1.tex
│   ├── chapter_2.tex
│   ├── chapter_3.tex
│   ├── chapter_4.tex
│   ├── chapter_5.tex
│   ├── Cosine Similarity_files
│   │   ├── Cosine Similarity_17_0.png
│   │   └── Cosine Similarity_22_0.png
│   ├── Language Models_files
│   │   └── Language Models_5_0.png
│   └── nb_preamble.tex
├── convert_to_latex.sh
├── convert_to_pdf.sh
├── corpus_zika
├── Cosine Similarity_files
│   ├── Cosine Similarity_17_0.png
│   └── Cosine Similarity_22_0.png
├── Cosine Similarity.ipynb
├── Cosine Similarity.tex
├── Dicionario_zika.dict
├── Language Models_files
│   └── Language Models_5_0.png
├── Language Models.ipynb
├── Language Models.tex
├── Probabilistic Text Models.ipynb
├── Probabilistic Text Models.tex
├── README.md
├── Topic Modeling.ipynb
└── Topic Modeling.tex
```

I want to move `Cosine Similarity_files` into `Book/`, eventualy overwriting it if it is already there. I issue the natural command:

```
mv Cosine\ Similarity_files Book/
```

and I get the message `Directory not empty` WTF!? But it gets better if I ask it to move one level deeper:

```
mv Cosine\ Similarity_files Book/Cosine\ Similarity_files
```

It dutifully does what it wouldn't do before! it writes the source directory into the target directory!! WTF²!?!

Why is that? Does it make any sense?

Comment: It doesn't do what you think... It moves it _into_ the destination directory, it doesn't overwrite the destination; that is, you end up with `Book/Cosine\ Similarity_files/Cosine\ Similarity_files`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute `mv Cosine\ Similarity_files Book/` nothing happens because a directory with the same name that is not empty exists in the `Book` directory.

As don_crissti stated in the comments above, when you executed `mv Cosine\ Similarity_files Book/Cosine\ Similarity_files`, it moved `Cosine\ Similarity_files` to `Book/Cosine\ Similarity_files/Cosine\ Similarity_files`

If you want to overwrite any existing files within the directory you are moving, you will have to use the `-f` or `-i` option.

```
-f
--force
     Remove existing destination files and never prompt the user.

-i
--interactive
     Prompt whether to overwrite each existing destination file,
     regardless of its permissions.  If the response does not begin
     with `y' or `Y', the file is skipped.
```

Example: `mv -f Cosine\ Similarity_files Book/`

**Note: `-f` will not overwrite or merge directories within the directory you are trying to move. It will only overwrite files.**

If you want to merge or overwrite directories, you can use `rsync` with the  `--remove-source-files` option. [For more information look at this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127713/125535).

Comment: `mv -f Cosine\ Similarity_files Book/` will not work.  `-f` overwrites regular files but not directories.  It will not perform a recursive overwrite.

Comment: @grochmal yep; related: [Merging folders with mv?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/127712) and  [How to force overwrite non-empty directories using `mv`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107812)

Comment: @grochmal That is true. This will work for the OP's particular problem though. I will update my answer.

Comment: @ElixirofLove - Thanks.  I'd add a small reference to `rsync`, just for people that might come here looking for and answer and not bother reading comments.

Comment: @grochmal Just updated. Thank you for your help and suggestions.